# Gödel quantified?

Tags: lo.logic

Wouldn't it be nice to have a real $0\le r\le1$ accompanying any
axiom set $A$ so that (I have not the slightest idea how to define $r$ :-)
say, $r<0.147587$ means "$A$ is too weak to allow the Gödel trick" and
$r>0.945895$ is impossible due to Gödel? Or, say, $r(ZF+CH)>r(ZF+-CH)$
which decides once and for all which is "better"? In short, $r$
measuring the "proving power" of A quantitatively.

Anything done in that direction?

Comment: What is “the Gödel trick”, “impossible due to Gödel”, and “better”? This question is too vague. Please, see the FAQ.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this, but to a certain extent aren't these some form of sharps?

Comment: Chaitin attempted to characterise the strengths of axiom systems in terms of a real number derived from their informational content. I'm not sure he actually succeeded in a useful way.

Comment: "Possible to do the Godel trick" means "has no complete, consistent extensions" IMO.

Answer (score 4):

The question is pretty vague, but it sounds as if you might be interested in the work of Andreas Weiermann on phase transitions in logic.